# how to set android tab icon backgrounds to transparent

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I have these tabs in my android app. these icons are created in adobe illustrator with transparent background and they work well on iphone app. but on the android app for some reason they have that black square box around it. is there any way to remove that black square box?

I am using the following code to set the background and it does remove the black background between icons.

```
 for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
    }
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: are these nine-patch images?

Comment: Are the images on `.png` format?

Comment: Yes these are in .png format.

Comment: I am not sure if these are nine patch. I have never worked with them.

Comment: No these are not 9 patch images.  these images have a drop shadow around them but are transparent.